# Can't use libgpod in python on Zero W

Tags: raspbian-stretch, python-2.x

I have installed python-gpod on Raspbian lite Stretch, but can't get it to work.

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~$ uname -a
    Linux raspberrypi 4.14.30+ #1102 Mon Mar 26 16:20:05 BST 2018 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

This is what happens if I try to use the code.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ cd /usr/share/doc/python-gpod/examples
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/share/doc/python-gpod/examples$ ./toy_around.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./toy_around.py", line 30, in <module>
    import gpod
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpod/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from gpod import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpod/gpod.py", line 31, in <module>
    _gpod = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpod/gpod.py", line 30, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_gpod')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _gpod
```

This is what is installed:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpod/
_gpod.arm-linux-gnueabihf.so  gpod.py  gtkpod.py  __init__.py  ipod.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now solved.

```
apt install python-gobject
```

Does the trick.